# Is the zenkai referred to as an "auto-evolving mechanism" anywhere besides volume 10 of the "Dragon Ball Z" manga?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

The zenkai is referred to as the "auto-evolving mechanism" on the back of volume 10 of the *Dragon Ball Z* manga. Is it called that anywhere else?